# Using Global Variable in TypeScript - Node Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Using typescript in node express. Having problems of using global variable.   Want to use the same global array variable  tokenList:tokList in the imported module, current module and middleware. Tried lot of ways its not working How can i do it?

Provided my apirouter file below .  Want to use variable tokenList:tokList in current apirouter file and  in imported users.ts file and in tokenchecker.js middleware .

```
import express from 'express';
import { permissionsRoute } from './permissions';
import { rolesRoute } from './roles';
import { usersRoute } from './users';
import usersList from '../../mocks/users.json';

// import config from  './config.json';


const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');  
const config = require('./config');
//const config = require('./config');
//const tokenList:any[]=new Array();
// interface TokenResponse {
//     status: string;
//     token: string;
//     refreshToken :string;
//   }

interface tokList {
    [key: string]: any;
}

var tokenList:tokList=[];
// using the middleware below
apiRouter.use(require('./tokenChecker'))
```

Provided the middleware file tokenChecker.js below

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('./config')

module.exports = (req,res,next) => {
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token']
  // decode token
  if (token) {
    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({"error": true, "message": 'Unauthorized access.' });
        }
      req.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
        "error": true,
        "message": 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
}
```

users.ts typescript file  below

```
import express from 'express';
// @ts-ignore squash JSON compiler warning
import users from '../../mocks/users.json';

export const usersRoute: express.Handler = (_req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(users);
};
```

Comment: You don't typically use globals in node.js and it is not a recommended practice to use global.  You define/create a variable in a module and you export that so anyone else who wants to use it can then import it.  You don't show what you're trying to create and how you're trying to use it, but it seems you can just make a module specifically for the `tokenList`, have that module create it, initialize it and export it and then have any modules with routes that wants to use it can import the `tokenList` module to get access to the shared data.

Comment: Thanks for the info will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a separate module for exporting variable.  import into the modules that requires the global variable Thanks to  jfriend00 comments